# React Type '{ hasInputs: boolean; bg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & boolean'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am pretty new to react. I have this error. I am passing a boolean value as a prop to a component. But this is the full error i am getting;

```
Type '{ hasInputs: boolean; bg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & boolean'.
Type '{ hasInputs: boolean; bg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'true'.ts(2322)
```

In my home.tsx component this is what i have

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "../../components/Header";

export default class ProHome extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header hasInputs={false} bg={'bg-blue-500'} />
           </div>
        );
    }
 }
```

Then in my header.tsx this is my

```
export default function Header(hasInputs: boolean, bg:string) {

    return (
        <div className={`h-2/3 ${bg} h-[500px] lg:h-screen lg:${bg}`}>
             {
                    hasInputs && <div className="flex w-full">
                    <input className="h-14 px-4 py-2 w-full" placeholder="Search Skill" />
                    <button className="bg-red-500 px-4 py-2 text-white">
                        <SearchIcon className="h-5 w-5"></SearchIcon>
                    </button>
                </div>
                }
        </div>
    );
 }
```

I get the error listed above and the div is showing even when hasInputs is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments that are being passed into your component `Header`, are accessible via the props Object:

```
export default function Header(props: { hasInputs: boolean, bg: string }) {...}
```

Then you can access hasInputs inside your component like this: `props.hasInputs`